# Visual Studio 2017 lock-up during add-in debugging/app deployment failures

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin

Using VS 2017 15.5.6 and I'm seeing two separate issues with Add-in development:

1. Failure to deploy the App with the message:

   > Install SharePoint Add-in: The system cannot find the file specified.

   However, the App package is successfully deployed. Re-running the Deployment step succeeds.
2. VS locks up during <kbd>F5</kbd> debugging of an Add-in (SharePoint or provider hosted). These same lockups do not occur with a CSOM-based Windows Service running as a console application.

For the second issue, I've already run devenv /resetsettings with no improvement.